# How do I Implement a lambda function in this way

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataset

For a dataset like this, how do i create another column (using pandas and lambda function) which works something like this.
In the new column, for all "Mary"s in the list which extends beyond the 5, income will be doubled. Otherwise, It remains the same.
https://gyazo.com/c2d2c356877d4f15e3e1f292e52164a7

Comment: Can you please include the dataframe as code in your question? Is way more readable and inclusive, and also easier for us to try things out.

Comment: What do you mean when you say which extends beyond the 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't really need a lambda function or something similar. You could try using [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) to select the "income" column from the rows where "name" is `"Mary"`, and do the same to set and get those values:

```
>>> df.loc[(df["name"] == "Mary"), "income"] = df.loc[(df["name"] == "Mary"), "income"] * 2
>>> df
   id  name  age  income  married
0   1  Paul   31   50000     True
1   2   Tim   45   70000    False
2   3  Mary   90   50000     True
3   4  Tony   20    5000    False
4   5   Sam   35  100000     True
```